# Web service abstract type as return value

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I am using Web Services in my web project.
I wrote a web service that returns IEnumerable:

```
[WebMethod]
public IEnumerable<Something> GetSomething() {
    IEnumerable<Something> result = ....
    ....
    return result;
}
```

Now, `result` can be anything that implements IEnumerable and therefore can be very complicated object to send to the client.
What do you think? Does it better to return specific type then abstract type (because the unaware of the return type)?
For example, I can create a DTO class for IEnumerable that holds simple arrey or something like that.
What is the best practice for this issues?

***UPDATE:***
I am using SeriptService with JSon and not with SOAP Xml. Up to now I was able to return IEnumerable - maybe because the underlaying enumerable was serialized item. What do you think?

Comment: It is more likely that your server will return an array (or some other collection) that is serializable and it will be deserialized into an IEnumerable for your client in a proxy.

Comment: @n8wrl: My client is a browser. Doesn't IEnumerable serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this might be fine as you specify the concrete type of your object, i.e. in your case `Something`.

The usage of a DTO is normally just used to

- decouple your object model from the one exposed to your clients through the webservice s.t. when your model changes you don't risk to break your webservice-api
- to reduce the amount of data transferred to the client. The goal is to keep webservice calls as performant as possible and hence you should optimize the data sent to the client.

Comment: I didn't understand from your answer. Do you think it is better to return Somthing[] then return IEnumerable<Something> ?

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` will be easily serialized by most serializers.
It is just a value which can be queried to get a list of item.

One this you need to be beware of here is that in case you use a yield return to create the enumerable then the method code which generate the enumerable will execute when the serializer starts to fetch the objects from the enumerable and start decoding them. So even if you have a data base call inside the method which generate the enumerable using yield return pattern, that data base call will happen after the return statement in your web method i.e when the serializer starts consuming the enumerable.

Comment: Does the fact that the db call happen after the return statement is wrong use?

Comment: Hmm.. it makes things complicated... from debugging point of view and normal code flow point of view